# Where to ask about Myspace clones (it seems to be dead)?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I posted the question *[Myspace is dead. What are the alternatives?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/8356/myspace-is-dead-which-alternatives)* to music.stachexchange.com where I basically ask if [Myspace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myspace) is still a valid network on where to put my music and, if not, for information about another site where to upload my music.

However, I'm not so sure that's the most appropriate network.

Where should a question like this be posted?

Comment: Well, you've already [asked it on the Music SE](http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/8356/myspace-is-dead-which-alternatives).

Comment: I'm not totally sure, as I don't know the scope of Music.SE...but that questions *sounds* off-topic on the whole network.

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby on the WHOLE network? why?

Comment: @DanieleB: Because it is a subjective poll question which lacks a definitive answer. That kind of questions is pretty much discouraged throughout the whole network with a *few* exceptions. (One such exception is Programmers, but I never understood the rules, so I let Chris and Anna speak for their site and I always default to *No* ;P ). *If* such a question is allowed can easily be figured out by reading the FAQ *and* asking on the appropriate Meta.

Comment: I'd say there's likely not a right site. I suggest for an answer, however, you look at Soundcloud.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a valid question for any Stack Exchange site I'm afraid. It's not a music question, it's a [shopping request](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) where there is no correct answer, and even if one answer was ideal, it'd likely it'll be replaced when a new service comes along, making that answer incorrect / obsolete.

The point is that it's not a problem you need solving, it's a resource issue. You don't know where to go to find out about 'x'. If your question was specifically about Myspace (that is, does Myspace still contain enough active users to make it worth the time to manage and update my page regularly) then that's *possibly* on topic on music.se (it's best to check with them though as they may disagree), but asking for suggestions / examples / alternatives isn't on topic on any Stack Exchange site really.

<sup>For the record, the new Myspace is in beta, and it's pretty interesting and very music focused so maybe Myspace *is* going to be a good place for bands to post to again after all.</sup>